# How to count odd or even numbers between particular elements?

Tags: c++, arrays

[image]

Hi everyone!!! I was writing contest and actually this is not difficult question but I stuck on it. Please help, here my code that passed only three tests and failed on fourth test. Answer must not use function and pointers. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
  long long int n;
  cin>>n;
  long long int a[n];

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>a[i];
  }
  long long int max=a[0],min=[0],ind1=0,ind2=0;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]>=max) {
      max=a[i];
      ind2=i;
    }
    if(a[i]<=min) {
      min=a[i];
      ind1=i;
    }
  }


  int sum=0;
  if(ind1<ind2)
  for(int i=ind1+1;i<ind2;i++){
    if(a[i]%2==0) sum++;
  }
  else if(ind1>ind2)
  for(int i=ind2+1;i<ind1;i++){
    if(a[i]%2==0) sum++;
  }

  cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the test case that you fail on? What is your expected output? What is your actual output? Please fix your whitespace. You're not paying by the horizontal or vertical space. It will make it easier for me to read.

Comment: @Dalmayan Describe the task in the question instead of providing a reference. For example it is unclear what to do if the sequence contains two or more maximum or minimum values.

Comment: @Dalmayan Your code in any case has undefined behavior because the variables min and max are initialized by indeterminate values.

Comment: BTW, `int a[n];` is Variable Length Array (VLA) and not part of the standard C++ language.  It could be an extension provided by a compiler.  Use `std::vector` for dynamic array.

Comment: Try using spaces between operators.  This has no effect on execution speed and negligible affect on the build time.  It has a great effect on the readability of your program.

Comment: thanks @ThomasMatthews I got you. Victor, I got you also, but vector is difficult to me, can we solve with just arrays?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to count the number of even elements between the min and max element in the array?

It may have failed the last test because you set initial min/max to garbage. In the case where a[0] is initialised to zero, and all the elements in the array are negative, the reported max will be incorrect, for example. You need to set max to the minimum integer and vice versa.

Comment: yes, the question is as you understand, and what can be minimum integer to max and what you mean on vice versa? )))

Comment: @Dalm, fill the array (or at least take the first input), and THEN set min/max to be a[0]. The alternative is to set min and max to the maximum and minimum (respectively) values for their type. `min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();`

Comment: Yes, as John said!

Comment: int a[n]; 
  //added only this line
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) a[i]=0;
  
added this line but it didnt pass same fourth test

Comment: Is an array really necessary?

Comment: arrays easier to understand to me, I edited code, but no result,what may be next mistake?